# Most efficient way to look for value in xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I need to get some value from.

There are several ways to do it:

- XmlReader
- XmlDocument
- XDocument
- XmlTextReader
- XmlSerializer

  1. Can someone please explain when to use each of them?
  2. If I need just get one value from my XML file - which one should I use to do it the most efficient way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you are not satisfied with Linq then try below explainer...
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/658297/XMLDocument-vs-XDocument-vs-XmlReader-vs-LINQ-to-X

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string path = Server.MapPath("[pathofXMLFile]"); 
System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xml.Load(path);
System.Xml.XmlNodeList t = xml.GetElementsByTagName("[tagname]"); 
string ht = t[0].InnerXml;
```

use relative path in locating your xml file hope this help you thanks

Comment: i know how to use each of them .. i want to know when to use each of them

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to parse the xml is to use the LINQ to XML
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061(v=vs.90).aspx may be useful

Comment: Try this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/658297/XMLDocument-vs-XDocument-vs-XmlReader-vs-LINQ-to-X